# Como implementar o VoidCallback numa Lista de Itens para listar num Gridview?

Tags: flutter, dart

Eu tentei seguir o tutorial deste link http://www.macoratti.net/19/07/flut_gridv1.htm pois tem uma listagem de itens em gridview mais próximo do que quero utilizar.

E então eu tentei adicionar uma opção de tornar esses itens clicáveis e fiz algumas pequenas modificações mas está dando erro na opção **VoidCallback**.

O erro retornado são estes:

1. `Invalid constant value - line 38`
2. `The values in a const list literal must be constants - line 38`
3. `Const variables must be initialized with a constant value - line 38`

A parte do código que está dando erro é esse:

```
class ItemExemplo {
  const ItemExemplo({this.titulo, this.icon, this.onPressBtn});
  final String titulo;
  final IconData icon;
  final VoidCallback onPressBtn;
}

const List<ItemExemplo> itenslist = const <ItemExemplo>[
  const ItemExemplo(titulo: 'Carro', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  const ItemExemplo(titulo: 'Bike', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  const ItemExemplo(titulo: 'Barco', icon: Icons.directions_boat),

  // o onPressBtn da linha abaixo é onde esta dando o erro, mas preciso dele pra função onTap do Widget que será exibido no grid.

  const ItemExemplo(titulo: 'Ônibux', icon: Icons.directions_bus, onPressBtn: () => print("Teste")),
];
```

Eu até entendo que o erro ta nas constantes, mas será que estou no caminho correto ou deveria refazer de outra maneira totalmente diferente? tem outro modo mais correto de fazer isso e que funcione?

Como ainda não existe um snippet para flutter aqui no SO eu coloquei o código completo no DartPad no link abaixo:

https://dartpad.dev/96d51e9f55496f4125ab6697d1a639e4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você pode notar, o problema é relacionado as constantes.

Você pode resolver deixando seu callback também constante, da seguinte forma:

```
void onClick() {
  print("Teste");
}

const List<ItemExemplo> itenslist = [
  ItemExemplo(titulo: 'Carro', icon: Icons.directions_car),
  ItemExemplo(titulo: 'Bike', icon: Icons.directions_bike),
  ItemExemplo(titulo: 'Barco', icon: Icons.directions_boat),
  ItemExemplo(
      titulo: 'Ônibux',
      icon: Icons.directions_bus,
      onPressBtn: onClick)
];
```

Outro ponto que pode ser melhorado é na classe `ItensCard`:

```
class ItensCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ItensCard({Key key, this.item}) : super(key: key);
  final ItemExemplo item;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2;
    return Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () => item.onPressBtn(),
          splashColor: Colors.amber,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(item.icon, size: 80.0, color: textStyle.color),
                  Text(item.titulo, style: textStyle),
                ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Altere o parâmetro `onTap()` da seguinte forma:

```
onTap: item.onPressBtn,
```

Apenas os itens que possuírem a propriedade `onPressBtn` preenchida terão o efeito de click, assim não irá gerar erros caso a propriedade esteja nula.

Comment: Obrigado por responder, mas isso ainda não ta dando certo, ele resolve na questão quando o callback executa apenas um simples `print`, mas se eu tento usar outro metodo como um `Navigator.of(context).push` ele da outro erro de `A value of type 'Future<Null>' can't be returned from function 'onClick'`. Desculpe minha ignorância sobre esse assunto, ainda estou aprendendo sobre flutter.

Comment: Como você disse, resolveu o seu problema, que é o que você tinha dúvidas e estava especificado no teu exemplo. Agora você está enfrentando um outro problema diferente amigo.

Comment: Altere a sua pergunta e adicione um exemplo desse problema que você citou referente ao `Navigator`. Uma dica (Não me leve a mal), quando for fazer perguntas, não oculte informações, ainda não sabemos lidar direito com bolas de cristal xD

Comment: Desculpe amigo, como disse ainda estou aprendendo sobre flutter, pensei que fazer um callback  de **VoidCallback** que fosse usado como onPressBtn num gridview serveria para todos os tipos de callbacks assim como num ontap ou um onpress de qualquer Widget, não sabia q um estilo anularia o outro. Mas fiquei hj o dia todo tentando resolver isso e acho q encontrei uma solução, vou postar jaja. Mesmo assim muito obrigado e me desculpa meus erros.

Answer (score 3):

Escolhi a resposta acima do Matheus como correta por ser justo a resposta que responde a minha pergunta. Mas eu encontrei outra solução para o meu problema e resolvi da forma abaixo, então as duas respostas estão corretas para quem precisar futuramente.

Na minha solução eu eliminei as linhas de listagens e modifiquei o construtor do widget ItensCard da seguinte forma, adicionando além do callback também coloquei mais uma opção para cores dos icones:

```
class ItensCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ItensCard({this.title, this.icon, this.colorItem, this.onPressBtn});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
  final MaterialColor colorItem;
  final VoidCallback onPressBtn;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2;
    return Card(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: onPressBtn,
          splashColor: Colors.amber,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Icon(icon, size: 80.0, color: colorItem),
                  Text(title, style: textStyle),
                ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

E agora em vez de eu usar a listagem no gridview como fazia antes dessa forma:

```
 children: List.generate(itenslist.length, (index) {
      return Center(
        child: ItensCard(item: itenslist[index]),
      );
    }),
```

Agora eu adiciono a propria lista direto no gridview dessa forma:

```
children: <Widget>[
    ItensCard(title: 'Carro', icon: Icons.directions_car, colorItem: Colors.blue, onPressBtn: () => print("Teste Carro")),
    ItensCard(title: 'Bike', icon: Icons.directions_bike, colorItem: Colors.red, onPressBtn: () => print("Teste Bike")),
    ItensCard(title: 'Barco', icon: Icons.directions_boat, colorItem: Colors.pink, onPressBtn: () => print("Teste Barco")),
    ItensCard(title: 'Ônibus', icon: Icons.directions_bus, ncolorItem: Colors.green, onPressBtn: () => print("Teste Ônibus")),
  ]);
```

Isso pra mim no meu caso me poupou mais linhas de códigos reduzindo bastante o tamanho, e também me facilitou o trabalho. Não sei se é útil pra todo mundo mas esta sendo muito util pra mim.

Segue o link da solução para visualização no DartPad:

https://dartpad.dev/96d51e9f55496f4125ab6697d1a639e4